How to delete any existing file from destination directory before copy from source directory in apache camel?
On sftp server, I want to delete any existing file from destination folder if exist before placing a new file from source to destination in camel, is there any way to delete file and I want to write only one camel route for this activity.

If file exists then it should automatically get overridden. That is the default behavior as far as I remember. Did you try doing this?

Yes see the docs for the ftp component about the file exists option and what you can configure this as
